# Copying Functions Across Networks

Tags: networking, go, closures, function-pointers

Using Go, I am trying to write code to transfer a closure across a network from computer A to computer B to allow computer B to execute the closure. For example

Computer A:

```
c1 := func() { fmt.Println("Hello World") }
// somehow transfer c1 to Computer B
```

Computer B:

```
c2 := // receive closure from Computer A
c2()
```

With the result being to print "Hello World" on the second computer. Is anybody aware of a method for this?

Comment: This is not exactly what Go is for. As such, you will have a hard to achieving it with standard Go. Having said that, there is a port of Go with a modified runtime and toolchain, which does allow you to do just that: [Go Circuit](http://www.gocircuit.org/).

Comment: Implicit RPC will make you sad.

Comment: If you want to execute code remotely without defining it in advance, you can compile a Lua VM with your app: https://github.com/aarzilli/golua . For now, there's no pure Go public implementation of a Lua VM, so you need C bindings.

Comment: @Dustin: Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. At least not until some fancy NaCl support is added.